# Svelte bind select with options based on if-else

Tags: svelte

I am making a search/filter for a form builder application that shows different filter types depending on the type of the question. For example, a numeric question displays filters for less/greater/equal while a text input displays filters for contains/exact/regex.

```html
<script>
    let questionType: string;
    let filterType: string;
</script>

<select bind:value={questionType}>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="numeric">Numeric</option>
</select>

<select bind:value={filterType}>
    {#if questionType === 'text'}
        <option value="contains">Contains</option>
        <option value="exact">Exact</option>
        <option value="regex">Regex</option>
    {:else if questionType === 'numeric'}
        <option value="lessThan">Less than</option>
        <option value="equalTo">Equal to</option>
        <option value="greaterThan">Greater than</option>
    {/if}
</select>
```

If I select a different question type, the filter options update accordingly; however, the bound `filterType` variable does NOT update. How can I get the `filterType` variable to update whenever the options change? I tried setting `selected` on one of the options but this does not do anything. This is causing my app to crash because it calls string functions on a number.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for the unexpected behaviour caused by the if-else block inside the select element could be to either set the initial values of `filterType` via a reactive statement whenever `questionType` changes

```
<script>
    let questionType;
    let filterType;

    $: if(questionType === 'text') {
        filterType = 'contains'
    }else {
        filterType = 'lessThan'
    }
</script>

<select bind:value={questionType}>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="numeric">Numeric</option>
</select>

<select bind:value={filterType}>
    {#if questionType === 'text'}
    <option value="contains">Contains</option>
    <option value="exact">Exact</option>
    <option value="regex">Regex</option>
    {:else if questionType === 'numeric'}
    <option value="lessThan">Less than</option>
    <option value="equalTo">Equal to</option>
    <option value="greaterThan">Greater than</option>
    {/if}
</select>
```

or via an [`action`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) ([tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions) / [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/adding-parameters-to-actions)) whenever the elements are created

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7304c64a8b734cac8b80d80de8bb31d2?version=3.52.0)

```
<script>
    let questionType;
    let filterType;
    
    function select(node) {
        filterType = node.value
    }
</script>

<select bind:value={questionType}>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="numeric">Numeric</option>
</select>

<select bind:value={filterType}>
    {#if questionType === 'text'}
    <option value="contains" use:select>Contains</option>
    <option value="exact">Exact</option>
    <option value="regex">Regex</option>
    {:else if questionType === 'numeric'}
    <option value="lessThan" use:select>Less than</option>
    <option value="equalTo">Equal to</option>
    <option value="greaterThan">Greater than</option>
    {/if}
</select>
```